# How do I use find () in mongodb with a conditional to use one field or another?

Tags: database, mongodb, mongo-shell

I have to return documents that are between two dateTime values ​​or if the dateTime field does not exist, use the createdAt field.
I'm using this query:

```
{ dateTime: { $gte: 1554087600000, $lte: 1609431033000 } }
```

But sometimes the dateTime field doesn't exist, so in this case, I have to use the createdAt field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use `$or` to filter by one value or another and `$and` with `$exists` to ensure the query will be fetch docuemtns where `dateTime` does not exist:

This query will get `dateTime` values if the are betwwen `$gte` and `$lte` specified or will get the document where `dateTime` does not exists and `createdAt` field match the criteria `$gte`/`$lte`.

```js
db.collection.find({
  "$or": [
    {
      "dateTime": {"$gte": 1,"$lte": 2}
    },
    {
      "$and": [
        {"dateTime": {"$exists": false},},
        {"createdAt": {"$gte": 1,"$lte": 2}}
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/InCKrNWNDAq)